# How can I return None when a given enum is not a certain variant?

Tags: rust

I have the following enum defined:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Core;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Mem;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Atag {
    Core(Core),
    Mem(Mem),
    Cmd(&'static str),
    Unknown(u32),
    None,
}
```

I would like to implement a function on this enum which "filters out" certain enum values. I have the following:

```
impl Atag {
    /// Returns `Some` if this is a `Core` ATAG. Otherwise returns `None`.
    pub fn core(self) -> Option<Core> {
        match self {
            Atag::Core => Some(self),
            _ => None
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why, but the compiler complains:

```
error[E0532]: expected unit struct/variant or constant, found tuple variant `Atag::Core`
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
17 |             Atag::Core => Some(self),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ not a unit struct/variant or constant
help: possible better candidate is found in another module, you can import it into scope
   |
1  | use Core;
   |
```

I also tried a comparison approach:

```
pub fn core(self) -> Option<Core> {
    if self == Atag::Core {
        Some(self)
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `Atag`
  --> src/main.rs:20:12
   |
20 |         if self == Atag::Core {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `Atag`
```

Comment: Conventionally, this function would be called `into_core`; a common pattern for such methods on enums.

Comment: [The specific naming convention I mention](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#ad-hoc-conversions-follow-as_-to_-into_-conventions-c-conv).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is just a limitation of the pattern matching and is designed to prevent unexpected behavior.

The full "definition" of an `Atag` with type `Core` is `Atag::Core(raw::Core)`. Obviously, the contents of the `Core` are irrelevant to you, but the compiler needs to know that everything is "accounted for" because the compiler is a stickler for the rules. The easiest way to get around this is to use the "anything pattern", `_`, much like you did to match non-`Core` variants.

```
impl Atag {
    /// Returns `Some` if this is a `Core` ATAG. Otherwise returns `None`.
    pub fn core(self) -> Option<Core> {
        match self {
            // The compiler now knows that a value is expected,
            // but isn't necessary for the purposes of our program.
            Atag::Core(_) => Some(self),
            _ => None
        }
    }
}
```

To ignore multiple values, you'd use `Something::Foo(_, _)` - one underscore for each value in the variant, or `Something::Foo(..)` to ignore everything.

Remember that, unlike in some other languages, a Rust enum is not "just" a collection of different types. Data associated with an enum value is a part of it, just like the fields of a structure. So `self == Atag::Core` isn't a meaningful statement because it ignores the data associated with a `Core`. A `Foo(0)` is different than a `Foo(12)`, even if they're both of the `Foo` variant.

I'd also like to point out [`if let`](https://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/if_let.html), which is - as far as I can tell - the closest option to a standard `if` statement without defining a custom `is_core` function on `Atag` (which, given the existence of `match` and `if let`, is basically unnecessary).

```
impl Atag {
    /// Returns `Some` if this is a `Core` ATAG. Otherwise returns `None`.
    pub fn core(self) -> Option<Core> {
        if let Atag::Core(_) = self {
            Some(self)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't see how this would compile; `Some(self)` is of type `Option<Atag>`, not `Option<Core>`.

Comment: Hang on. @JamesTaylor, did you want to return *`self`* (an `Atag::Core`, return type `Option<Atag>`), or *the Core held by `self`* (a `Core` struct, return type `Option<Core>`)? Because I assumed you wanted the former and didn't check the type signature as closely as I should have. If you want the latter, that changes things.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this to chain functions together nicely. In that case, you want to return the unwrapped core type, rather than just the enum.

I also found it easier to not consume the input, and so accepted a `&self` argument an returned an `Option<&Core>`. But you can have both.

The [Rust convention](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#ad-hoc-conversions-follow-as_-to_-into_-conventions-c-conv) has `as_X` as the reference-based conversion and `into_X` as the conversion that consumes the value. For example:

```
impl Atag {
    fn as_core(&self) -> Option<&Core> {
        if let Atag::Core(ref v) = self {
            Some(v)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
    fn into_core(self) -> Option<Core> {
        if let Atag::Core(v) = self {
            Some(v)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Atag::Core(Core {});
    let m = Atag::Mem(Mem {});
    assert_eq!(c.as_core().map(|cc| "CORE_REF"), Some("CORE_REF"));
    assert_eq!(m.as_core().map(|cc| "CORE_REF"), None);
    // Consume c - we cant use it after here...
    assert_eq!(c.into_core().map(|cc| "NOM NOM CORE"), Some("NOM NOM CORE"));
    // Consume m - we cant use it after here...
    assert_eq!(m.into_core().map(|cc| "NOM NOM CORE"), None);
}
```